# Active Directoryにてドメイン参加しようとするとDNSエラーが出る

Tags: windows, dns, active-directory

#### 現象

Active Directoryにてドメインに参加しようとするとDNSエラーが出力される。

自宅のLAN環境にWindows Server 2019のドメインコントローラを追加し、
Windows 2019のクライアントサーバーからドメインに参加しようとするとエラーとなります。
詳細をクリックすると以下のメッセージが出力されました。

#### エラー内容

ドメイン "対象ドメイン" の Active Directory ドメイン コントローラー (AD DC) を検索するために、使用される DNS の Service Location (SRV) リソース レコードを照会したときに、次のエラーが発生しました:

```
エラー: "タイムアウト期間が経過したため、この操作は終了しました。"
(エラー コード 0x000005B4 ERROR_TIMEOUT)

クエリは _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs."対象ドメイン" の SRV レコードに対するものでした

名前解決のためにこのコンピューターによって使用される DNS サーバーが応答していません。
このコンピューターは、次の IP アドレスを持つ DNS サーバーを使用するように構成されています:

“ドメインコントローラーのIP“

このコンピューターがネットワークに接続されていること、これらの DNS サーバーの IP アドレスが正しいこと、
および少なくとも 1 つの DNS サーバーが実行中であることを確認してください。
```

なお、実施した内容は以下となります。

#### 環境

＜ドメインコントローラー＞

・ベンダー
AWS

・OS
Windows server 2019

・ネットワーク設定

ipv4アドレス
サブネット
デフォルトゲートウェイ
DNS →ipv4と同じ

＜クライアントサーバ＞
・ベンダー
AWS

・OS
Windows server 2019

・ネットワーク設定

DNS →ipv4と同じ

#### 実施した内容

▼両サーバ
・Windowsファイアウォール設定無効化

・AWS セキュリティグループ設定を確認
→インバウンドルールにて（RDP、ICMPのみ全開放）、アウトバウンドルールはすべて許可

・相互に通信可能な状況か確認
→コマンドプロンプトよりpingを飛ばし、どちらからも通信可能なことを確認済み

▼ドメインコントローラー側
・DNS設定で、「前方参照ゾーン」に対象ドメインが含まれていることを確認

・DNSサービスの再起動
→状況変わらず

・コマンドプロンプトにてdcdiagを実行
→「DFSREvent」以外はパスしている。
これは初めのドメコンでは出るものなので問題なさそう。

#### 見解

エラーの詳細を見る限り、DNSサービスの設定周りが上手くいっていないことはわかるのですが、サービスは問題なく起動しているのと、DNSサーバのIPもドメインコントローラーのIP(ipconfig /allで確認したもの)になっているので間違ってはないはず。
初めてWindows serverに触る為、根本的な部分が間違っている可能性もあると思います。
お手数ですが、色々とご教授頂けますと幸いです。